# Form.AutoEngineer not being recognized

Tags: html, coldfusion, cfquery, cfoutput

so, I updated a lot in with this code from the casing, the hidden input field. I have not been able to change the validation or work on SQL Injections, but I am getting there. I am having 2 main problems and they both deal with elements not beinga able to be foind in the form.

```
<cfquery name="pri" datasource="#TEST#">
        select priority
        from tbl_erd_priority
        where unit_supported = '#orgs.unit_supported#'
        order by priority asc
    </cfquery>
    <!---get engineer data--->
     <cfquery name="geteng" datasource="#TEST#">
        select *
        from tbl_erd_eng
        where unit_supported = '#orgs.unit_supported#' 
        order by engineer_name asc
    </cfquery>
    <!---get all data--->
    <cfquery name="eng_work" datasource="#TEST#">
        select *
        from tbl_erd
        where 
        <cfif isdefined("form.btn_id2")>id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.id#">
        <cfelseif isdefined("url.id")>id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.id#"></cfif>
    </cfquery>
    <!---get the weapon system for below--->
    <cfquery name="ws" datasource="#TEST#">
        select *
        from tbl_erd_weapsys
        where unit_supported = '#orgs.unit_supported#'  
    </cfquery>
    <!---get area data for management listings--->
    <cfquery name="getarea" datasource="#TEST#">
        select area
        from tbl_erd_area
        where unit_supported = '#orgs.unit_supported#'
    </cfquery>
     <!---get eng data--->
        <cfquery name="prev" datasource="#TEST#">
            select engineer1
            from tbl_erd
            where 
            <cfif isdefined("form.btn_id2")>id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.id#">
            <cfelseif isdefined("url.id")>id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.id#"></cfif>
        </cfquery>

    <!---get information for cmxg auto comments---> 
    <cfif #orgs.unit_supported# eq 'TEST'>
        <cfquery name="getrecta" datasource="#TEST#">
            select * 
            from tbl_erd 
            where id = '#form.id#'
        </cfquery>

        <cfif '#form.engineer1#' is not '#getrecta.engineer1#'>
            <cfquery name="eecdinsert" datasource="#TEST#">
                insert into erd_robins.dbo.tbl_erd_eng_notes (unit_supported, erd_id, eng_notes)
                values (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#orgs.unit_supported#">,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.id#">,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.auto_engineer#">);
            </cfquery>
        </cfif>
    </cfif>

        <cfoutput>        
          <cfset prev_eng = #prev.engineer1#>
        </cfoutput>
<form action="" method="post" name="erd">
    <input type="hidden" name="proj_title_required" value="proj title is required">
    <input type="hidden" name="proj_user_notes_required" value="proj user notes are required">
    <input type="hidden" name="priority_required" value="priority is required">
    <input type="hidden" name="weapsystem_required" value="please provide a weapon system">
    <input type="hidden" name="engineer1_required" value="primary engineer is required">
    <input type="hidden" name="proj_user_type_required" value="please provide a proj type">
    <cfoutput>
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.id#" name="track_num">
        <input type="hidden" name="prev_eng" value="#prev.engineer1#">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.proj_number#" name="proj_number">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.poc_name#" name="poc_name">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.poc_phone#" name="poc_phone">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.username#" name="username">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.firstname#" name="firstname">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.lastname#" name="lastname">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.phone#" name="phone">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.email#" name="email">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.unit_supported#" name="unit_supported">
        <input type="hidden" value="#dateformat(now())#" name="startdate">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.bldg_num#" name="bldg_num">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.proj_type#" name="proj_type">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.proj_status#" name="proj_status">
        <input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.bnumber#" name="bnumber" />
        <input type="hidden" value="The Project Primary Engineer has been updated-(#dateformat(now(), 'mmm-dd-yyyy')# #timeformat(now(), 'hh:mm:ss tt')#)-#session.lastname#" name="auto_engineer">
    </cfoutput> 
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="ffffff">
            <cfoutput>
                <a href="erd_adm_manage.cfm?area=#eng_work.proj_user_type#&username=#session.username#&unit_supported=#orgs.unit_supported#" style="font: 8pt verdana; color: ff0000" target="userform"><u><b>back</b></u></a><br><br>
            </cfoutput>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="3" bgcolor="efefef" align="center" border="1" width="750"  bordercolor="e5e5e5">
                <tr bgcolor="f5ead8">
                    <td colspan="6" style="font: 9pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">
                        <b>"<cfoutput>#eng_work.proj_user_type#</cfoutput> Work Request" - <font color="0000ff">RE-ASSIGN</font> Form</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="f5ead8">
                    <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" colspan="6" valign="top">
                        <u>Use the following form to make your consideration:</u><br>
                        <br>
                        &nbsp;<font color="993399" size="3">*</font>&nbsp;<font color="006666" size="3">*</font>&nbsp; Are done prior to assignment - if they are to be updated
                        <!---show message coming into this page--->
                        <cfif isdefined("url.message")>
                        &nbsp;<b  style="font: 10pt verdana; color: ffff00">&loz;</b><b  style="font: 10pt verdana; color: 0033ff"><cfoutput>
                #iif(isvalid("string", url.message), de("#htmleditformat(url.message)#"), de("this is not valid text"))#
                </cfoutput></b>
                        </cfif> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <cfoutput query="eng_work">
                <tr bgcolor="f5ead8">
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <table border="2" bordercolor="cccccc" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"  width="350">
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">
                                    <font color="993399" size="3">*</font>&nbsp;Project Title:
                                </td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">
                                    <input type="text" label="proj_title" value="#proj_title#" name="proj_title" size="30">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">
                                    <font color="993399" size="3">*</font>&nbsp;Project Desc.:
                                </td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">
                                    <textarea style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" name="proj_user_notes" cols=33 rows=5 wrap="virtual">#proj_user_notes#</textarea>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>    
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                        <table border="2" bordercolor="cccccc" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"  width="400">
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Requestor:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">#firstname#&nbsp;#lastname#</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Email:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">#email#</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Phone:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">#phone#</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Track Num.:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">#id#</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Building:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">#bnumber#</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Org.:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">#unit_supported#</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="f5ead8">
                    <td valign="top" colspan="3">
                        <table border="2" bordercolor="cccccc" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"  width="350">
                            <cfif #orgs.unit_supported# eq '402d emxg'>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Alternate POC:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    #poc_name#
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Alternate POC Phone:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    #poc_phone#
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Date Assigned:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    #dateformat(now())#
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Date Submitted:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    #dateformat('#eng_work.dateofentry#', 'dd-mmm-yy')#
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <cfelseif #orgs.unit_supported# eq '402d cmxg'>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Alternate POC:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    #poc_name#
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Alternate POC phone:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    #poc_phone#
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Date Assigned:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    #dateformat(now())#
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Date Submitted:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    #dateformat('#eng_work.dateofentry#', 'dd-mmm-yy')#
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <cfelse>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Alternate POC:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    #poc_name#
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Alternate POC Phone:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    #poc_phone#
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Date Assigned:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    #dateformat(now())#
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Date Submitted:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    #dateformat('#eng_work.dateofentry#', 'dd-mmm-yy')#
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">Proj Num:</td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="f4f7f7" bordercolor="cccccc">#proj_number#</td>
                            </tr>
                            </cfif>
            </cfoutput>     
                        </table>
      </td>
                    <td valign="top" colspan="3">
                        <table border="2" bordercolor="cccccc" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"  width="400">    
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">
                                    <font color="0000cc" size="3">*</font>&nbsp;Primary Eng:
                                </td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bordercolor="cccccc">                                    
                                    <select name="engineer1"  style="font: 7pt verdana; color: 000033">
                                        <!---'reset' is the value needed to stop the clock for the current engineer assigned to this record--->
                                        <option value="reset">---Select----------</option>
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <cfoutput query="geteng">
                                        <option value="#htmleditformat(engineer_name)#" <cfif #engineer_name# is #eng_work.engineer1#>selected</cfif>>#htmleditformat(engineer_name)#</option> 
                                        </cfoutput> 
                                    </select>       
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Alternate Eng:
                                </td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    <select name="engineer2"  style="font: 7pt verdana; color: 000033">
                                        <option value="">---select----------</option>
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <cfoutput query="geteng">
                                        <option value="#htmleditformat(engineer_name)#" <cfif #engineer_name# is #eng_work.engineer2#>selected</cfif>>#htmleditformat(engineer_name)#</option> 
                                        </cfoutput> 
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" >
                                    <font color="993399" size="3">*</font>&nbsp;<cfif #orgs.unit_supported# eq '402d emxg' or #orgs.unit_supported# eq '402d cmxg'>Org:<cfelseif #orgs.unit_supported# eq '402d smxg'>Squadron<cfelse>Weapon System:</cfif>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    <select name="weapsystem"  style="font: 7pt verdana; color: 000033">
                                        <option value="">---select----------</option>
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <cfoutput query="ws">
                                        <option value="#htmleditformat(weapsys)#" <cfif #weapsys# is #eng_work.weapsystem#>selected</cfif>>#htmleditformat(weapsys)#</option> 
                                        </cfoutput> 
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">
                                    <font color="006666" size="3">*</font>&nbsp;Project Area:
                                </td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top" bordercolor="cccccc">
                                    <select name="proj_user_type"  style="font: 7pt verdana; color: 000033">
                                        <option value="">---select----------</option>
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <cfoutput query="getarea">
                                            <option value="#htmleditformat(area)#" <cfif #area# is #eng_work.proj_user_type#>selected</cfif>>#htmleditformat(area)#</option>
                                        </cfoutput>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr  bordercolor="f5ead8">
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">
                                    <font color="993399" size="3">*</font>&nbsp;Priority
                                </td>
                                <td style="font: 8pt verdana; color: 000000" align="left" valign="top">
                                    <select name="priority" style="font: 7pt verdana; color: 000033">
                                        <option value="">---select----------</option>
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <cfoutput query="pri">
                                        <option value="#htmleditformat(priority)#" <cfif #priority# is #eng_work.priority#>selected</cfif>>#htmleditformat(priority)#</option>
                                        </cfoutput>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>                   
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>           
                <tr bgcolor="f5ead8">
                    <td colspan="6" align="center">
                        <table border="2" bordercolor="cccccc" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"  width="500">    
                            <tr bordercolor="fef1de">                               
                                <td width="20%" style="font: 9pt verdana; color: 000000" align="center" valign="top">
                                    <input type="submit" name="btn_delete1" value=" Delete Request" style="font: 9pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif ; color: #cc0033; font-weight:bold;" onclick="return confirm('on the next page - please provide a reason for deleting this request')">
                                </td>
                                <td width="20%" style="font: 9pt verdana; color: 000000" align="center" valign="top">
                                    <input type="submit" name="btn_update2" value="Change Proj Type" style="font: 9pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif ; color: #006666; font-weight:bold;">
                                </td>
                                <td width="20%" style="font: 9pt verdana; color: 000000" align="center" valign="top">
                                    <input type="submit" name="btn_updaterequest2" value=" Update Request " style="font: 9pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif ; color: #993399; font-weight:bold;" onclick="return confirm('you are about to update this work request - are you sure?')">
                                </td>                           
                                <td width="40%" style="font: 9pt verdana; color: 000000" align="center" valign="top">
                                    <input type="submit" name="btn_assign2" value=" Assign Request " style="font: 9pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif ; color: #0000cc; font-weight:bold;" onclick="return confirm('you are about to assign this work request - are you sure?')">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>    
                    </td>   
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>           
</form>
```

Ok so tthe two elements I am having problems with are form.engineer1 and form.auto_engineer. The auto_engineer field is located in the output section of the area where the hidden input fields are. And the engineer1 field is located towards the bottom of the form. I am using the naming conventions right and everythign. I do not uncewrstand what the problem could be.

I hope thi is easier to read now, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no logic around the `cfquery` handling the `INSERT` that checks if the form was actually submitted.

Comment: BTW - The code is a mess with mixing the case of tags. Pick one, preferably lowercase, and stick with it.

Comment: Also, there is no reason to wrap a simple `cfset`. you could haev simply used `<cfsetPrev_Eng = PREV.Engineer1>`. Notice I took out the `#`. It seems that code has nothing to do with the problem, though, so why include it?

Comment: With a quick test, I see that particular value being passed on submit (assuming you meant "... AutoEngineer is undefined in Form ..."). But why does it even need to be a hidden textarea? Why not just another `<input type="hidden"...`? And are you possibly deleting the form structure at some point, leading to the `...undefined...` error?

Comment: Its not that bad geez...I'm cleaning this up a bit and will post it as an answer (with some improved logic).

Comment: @DanBracuk yep...lots of non-conventional stuff here. I created an answer that addressed the glaring stuff.

Comment: @FrankTudor yes, it is that bad.

Comment: @SinceForever ...I totally understand.  This code is 'pretty wild'.  I have a revision to my answer below on the query stuff.  Scott is right  about the queryparam stuff and a few other things. Why don't we head over to code review and you post some things there so we can help you improve all this?

Comment: Yea I don't see the original comment defending my honor anymore, but code already existed. Working with what I got before the deadline. And I am fairly new to ColdFusion

Answer (score 1):

Ok here are some improvements and notes for you.

First this select query. You are doing a select * query.  Are you wanting to to pull this to the page every time? Or only when you want to do an insert (that doesn't seem right).

```
<cfquery name="noteselect" datasource="#request.dsn#">
select * from tbl_erd_eng_notes
</cfquery>
```

On the next if statement and the insert query I have made changes too.

```
<cfif orgs.unit_supported eq 'test'>
<cfquery name="eecdinsert" datasource="#request.dsn#">
insert into erd_robins.dbo.tbl_erd_eng_notes (unit_supported, erd_id, eng_notes)
values (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#orgs.unit_supported#">,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.id#">,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.auto_engineer#">);
</cfquery>
</cfif>
```

In your insert query you are seeking some form vars and that orgs.unit_supported looks like a struct.

Anyways when we have an insert query from a form we usually look for a variable that will be present.  There are lots to choose from below.

To do this you would wrap your insert query with something like `<cfif isdefined(form.auto_engineer)></cfif>`

The next concern is that you are wide open for SQL injection. Consider using `<cfqueryparam>` See your code above for an example.

Removed the output tags and the hash tags.  You don't need to wrap cfoutput around cfset and you don't need hash tags for already set variables. `<cfset prev_eng = prev.engineer1>`

If you are posting this form to 'this' page the you can make the action blank and like magic the page will self post...(Unless you have a worker page that does stuff).

```
<form action="" method="post" name="erd">
```

But we will assume that you are not.

```
<form action="erd_adm_manage_action.cfm" method="post" name="erd">
```

Question are all your inputs for this form really supposed be 'hidden' or are you wanting to show stuff because you are informing them of stuff that they might have done wrong which would be confusing because that would be form handling logic not inputs).

But I have seen this when people aggregate form stuff like in form wizards.

This stuff here...Don't do this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="proj_title_required" value="proj title is required">
<input type="hidden" name="proj_user_notes_required" value="proj user notes are required">
<input type="hidden" name="priority_required" value="priority is required">
<input type="hidden" name="weapsystem_required" value="please provide a weapon system">
<cfif NOT isdefined("form.engineer1")> 
<input type="hidden" name="engineer1_required" value="primary engineer is required">    
 </cfif>
<input type="hidden" name="proj_user_type_required" value="please provide a proj type">
```

I understand what you want to do above but it is unorthodox and pretty wierd.

Consider form checks like this (after you click submit):

```
<cfif not isdefined("form.eng_work.proj_number")>
hey pal...you need to provide a project number...
</cfif>
```

...or something like that.

```
<cfoutput>
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.id#" name="track_num">
<input type="hidden" name="prev_eng" value="#prev.engineer1#">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.proj_number#" name="proj_number">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.poc_name#" name="poc_name">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.poc_phone#" name="poc_phone">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.username#" name="username">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.firstname#" name="firstname">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.lastname#" name="lastname">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.phone#" name="phone">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.email#" name="email">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.unit_supported#" name="unit_supported">
<input type="hidden" value="#dateformat(now())#" name="startdate">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.bnumber#" name="bnumber">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.bldg_num#" name="bldg_num">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.proj_type#" name="proj_type">
<input type="hidden" value="#eng_work.proj_status#" name="proj_status">
```

Now for the last part...the textarea:

You are hiding this? Ok. but you don't need to hide this in a text area. I put it in a hidden input. Note as long as your double quotes surrounding the value and single quotes inside your text strings. You should be all good.

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name="auto_engineer" 
       value="the primary engineer has been updated-(#dateformat(now(), 'mmm-dd-yyyy')# #timeformat(now(), 'hh:mm:ss tt')#)-#session.lastname#">
</cfoutput>
```

And that solves that problem.

Consider refactoring all this...and next time...hit up the [stack exchange code review website](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this type of thing.

Good luck!

Comment: Why would you show him the query without `cfqueryparam` and then tell him to change it? Tell him how to do it the right way and explain why that is the right way. Also, is that `INSERT` syntax compatible with other DBMS besides MySQL?

Comment: @ScottStroz You are absolutely right.  I am fixing up that query...and  reverting to his original

Comment: And now I feel better about voting it up :D

Comment: I am using the above insert statement now, but the problem I am having now is that it does the insert on page load instead of when the form submits. I have tried the button set to an IsDefined statement with no luck. Even tried IsValid (pretty sure that wouldn't work to begin with). Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Whem I say above insert I mean the above insert made by Frank.

Comment: It is these times that I wish I could delete post. I was not in the action page when I was writing this. Thank You for everyone's help though